# How status online/offline display from last activity in the table of SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So, i have this query:

```
$alt_user_result = execute_pdo_query("SELECT U.username, U.user_id, T.last_activity_time
FROM user_skills S, users U
LEFT JOIN user_status T ON U.user_id=T.user_id
WHERE S.user_id=U.user_id and S.task_type_id=? and S.permission='Yes';",
array($tablerow['task_type_id']));
```

and i'm doing something like this to display the status:

```
foreach($alt_user_result as $cur_user) {

 if($cur_user['user_id'] != 1){

   if( (time(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - time($cur_user['last_activity_time'])) < 300 ){
    echo "<option value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | online</option>";
   }
   else if( (time(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - time($cur_user['last_activity_time'])) >300){
    if( (time(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - time($cur_user['last_activity_time']))<1800 ) {
     echo "<option value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | idle</option>";
    }
   }
   else if( (time(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - time($cur_user['last_activity_time']))>1800 ){
     echo "<option value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | offline</option>";
   }
  }
  var_dump((time(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - time($cur_user['last_activity_time'])));
 }
 echo "<input type='submit' name='reassign' value='Reassign'/></select></form>";
}
```

the `last_activity_time` in my table is : `datetime`.

the `var_dump` result from the table are only zero and it's not correct, if i remove the `time()` it will show the difference between the times but with the `time()` it breaks;

What i need to do **IS** if last activity is <= 5 mins => status : online

if it's > 5mins and <= 30 mis => status : idle

if it's > 30 mins => status : offline.

What i'm doing wrong? any ideas?

Comment: Do you want solution by PHP or MySQL?

Comment: MySQL is working fine, i need the solution for PHP , thanks!

Comment: Try using `strtotime` instead of time.

Comment: @Lex my problem is to do the minus operation between two times `-` ... and i don't know if it ill work with Y-m-d format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given sql query for user status. You can directly use that column in in your loop. No need of if conditions.

```
$alt_user_result = execute_pdo_query("
SELECT U.username, U.user_id, T.last_activity_time,
case 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, T.last_activity_time ,NOW() ) <= 5 THEN 'online'
WHEN ( TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, T.last_activity_time ,NOW() ) > 5 AND 
   TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, T.last_activity_time ,NOW() ) <=30 ) THEN 'idle'
ELSE 'offline' END as user_status   
FROM user_skills S, users U
LEFT JOIN user_status T ON U.user_id=T.user_id
WHERE S.user_id=U.user_id and S.task_type_id=? and S.permission='Yes';",
array($tablerow['task_type_id']));
```

i.e.

```
echo "<option value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | $cur_user[user_status]</option>";
```

If you want to change status to image that can be managed.

```
echo "<option value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | ";

if( $cur_user[user_status]=='online') echo "<img src='online.jpg'/>";
else if( $cur_user[user_status]=='idle') echo"<img src='idle.jpg'/>";
else if( $cur_user[user_status]=='offline') echo "<img src='offline.jpg'/>";

echo "</option>";
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion but i need a php solution because i may change the 'online' to an image for example. thanks for your answer !

Comment: it works a little bit, i edited your query, thanks for your answer man! but the php stuff with the image is not really working, can you review it ? thanks !

Answer (score 2):

you can solve it with MySQL **[TIMESTAMPDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)** and **[CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)** function

```
SELECT * , TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
MINUTE , last_active, NOW( ) ) AS minuteDiff, 
CASE  
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , last_active, NOW( ) ) >30 THEN  'Offline'
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , last_active, NOW( ) ) > 4 THEN  'Idle'
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , last_active, NOW( ) ) THEN  'Online'    
END AS userStatus
FROM tbl_time
```

now check condition on `userStatus` column

### UPDATE

**Note :** You can use images or whatever you want it really not matter.

after above query, you can display it in php in given below way

```
<select name ="selectName" id ="selectID" > 
foreach($alt_user_result as $cu)
{

    switch($cu['userStatus'])
    {
        case 'Online' :
                        $txt = 'Online';
                        $img = 'images/online.png';
                        break;
        case 'Idle' :
                    $txt = 'Idle';
                    $img = 'images/idle.png';
                    break;
        case 'Offline' :
                    $txt = 'Offline';
                    $img = 'images/offline.png';
                    break;
        default : 
                // here you can set default value
    }

    if($cu['user_id'] != 1) {
      echo "<option value='$cu[user_id]'> $cu['username'] | $txt 
                /*  or you can show respective image */
                | <img src ='$img' alt='$txt' title='$txt'/>
            </option> ";
    } // end of if
} // end of foreach
</select>
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion but i need a php solution because i may change the 'online' to an image for example. thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

If want to get the difference between two dates, use php's dateTime. This function returns the difference between two dates, no matter wether the result is positive or negative, it will always just return the difference. You can then output it in whatever format you want:

```
function date_diff($date1,$date2){
    try {
        $d1Object = new DateTime($date1);
        $d2Object = new DateTime($date2);

        $diff = $d1Object->diff($d2Object);
    }

    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '';
    }
    //this returns the difference in years, e.g.
    //for more info, see php.net dateTime
    return $diff->y;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't write PHP, but something along these lines should get you started:

```
    foreach($alt_user_result as $cur_user) 
    {
        if($cur_user['user_id'] != 1)
        {
            $interval = time(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->diff(time($cur_user['last_activity_time']));

            $numSeconds = $interval->s + $interval->m * 60 + $interval->h * 60 * 60 + $interval->d * 60 * 60 * 24;

            $status = "offline";

            if ($numSeconds < 300)
            {
                $status="online";
            }
            else if ($numSeconds < 1800)
            {
                $status="idle";
            }

            echo "<option value='$cur_user[user_id]'>$cur_user[username] | ".$status."</option>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, as I said, I don't write PHP, so I can't give you the exact code to solve your problem. However, with a bit of editing, I think that the pattern  above should meet your needs (or you could just wait for somebody to give you exactly what you need).